# Is it possible to write an Android app that uses Google Maps on android device with OGL1.1?

Tags: android, android-mapview

It seems it's no longer possible to get an API key for API v1 and API V2 requires Open GL 2.0. My device does not have OGL 2 - so is it now physically impossible to write an app that uses a Map?

Intuitively this seems crazy but I've searched and searched and have yet to find an answer.

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My device does not have OGL 2 - so is it now physically impossible to write an app that uses a Map?

You cannot use Maps V2. You are welcome to use OpenStreetMap or other mapping engines.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, let me just 100% confirm there is _no_ other option to use Google Maps on this device? API V1 is definitely not an option?

I ask because on the same phone, The Google Map application works fine.

Comment: @user2452192: "API V1 is definitely not an option?" -- it is only an option if you have Maps V1 API keys. "I ask because on the same phone, The Google Map application works fine" -- you are welcome to raise several billion USD, acquire Google, and force them to allow third-party developers to continue using Maps V1.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. In the absence of V1 API keys, I shall now stop trying to get this working for my old phone.